# AngularJS templateUrl vs template - isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-template, plunker

I have the following directive:

```
offerListSorters.directive('offersSorter', ['myState', '$templateCache', function (myState, $templateCache){
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
      [...]
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    //templateUrl: 'partials/offersSorterDirective.html',
    template: $templateCache.get('partials/offersSorterDirective.html'),
    replace: true,
    transclude: true
  };
}]);
```

And I use Karma + Jasmine to test this code and it works. But now if I switch to the templateUrl (currently commented out), it doesn't work. I've created a [simple Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qE57VpL8XOyF8xjmmRdp?p=preview) to show this issue. When you compare sorter and bsorter directives, it looks as if the isolateScope() call on the compiled element breaks when I use templateUrl instead of template. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's the weirdest thing, I think this is actually a bug where if you're using a templateUrl, you don't get an isolated scope.  The template itself is loaded correctly, but the scope is never loaded. I've [updated the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHqHzzV4H8hjGhymctfW?p=preview) with some additional logging, checkout out the console and you'll see what I mean, `bsorter` doesn't get the ng-isolate-scope class and the scope is returned as undefined.

**Edit:**

I've updated the plnkr further to log a console message when the compile function is called.  This is pretty much the limit of my javascript/angularJS knowledge, but the bsorter compile function is logged as being called *after* the scope should be returned, unlike the sorter compile function which is called *before*.

Comment: Your edit is really onto something. I updated the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjFYFmcHS0uO3QXiN8KJ?p=preview) even further and it now works. I used $timeout which is not pretty. It looks to me as if with templateUrl Angular tries to first fetch the address, if it fails it uses the cache. But the HTTP request takes time to fail.

Comment: Googling with that extra bit of information it seems that it's a common issue not to be able to know when Angular is done modifying the DOM. It also seems that using $timeout or $evalAsync are the two most common ways to solve this. I guess this will do for now.

Comment: That's a definite gotcha when testing. Thanks for the follow up, that $timeout workaround is a handy trick to have.

Answer (score 0):

You should call isolateScope() in the it() function, not in beforeEach().

```
describe("Testing...", function(){
    var element, isoScope;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module("myApp");

        inject(function($rootScope, $compile){
            var scope = $rootScope.$new();
            element = $compile(angular.element("<sorter></sorter>"))(scope);
            // isoScope = element.isolateScope();  <- Move from here
            $rootScope.$digest();
        });
    });

    it("something...", function(){
        isoScope = element.isolateScope();  // <- to here
        expect(isoScope.someProp).toBe("someValue");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call $rootScope.$digest() after creating the directive via $compile, then it should work (right now you're calling the $digest() on the on your variable parentScope with is a new scope created with $rootScope.$new())