# AngularJS and $stateProvider : How to keep the context while replacing templateUrl by templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using $stateProvider with a routing table like this (simplified version):

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl:'menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl:'home.html'
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

This scheme works well, but while porting the project on another framework, loading the templates through an url was not an option anymore. I therefore had to refactor my code replacing the `templateUrl` property with the `template` one.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: "/app",
      abstract: true,
      template:UiRouter.template('menu.html'), // UiRouter now provides the menu.html template content
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

    .state('app.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          template:UiRouter.template('home.html'), // UiRouter now provides the home.html template content
        }
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

Unfortunately it seems that loading the template this way made me loss the scope. To explain, I have directives in the "menu.html" such as ion-Nav-Bar providing a controller (ionNavBar) which one is mandatory in another directive  into the home.html template. Using the templateUrl property works well but importing through template seems to [isolate the scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023269/angularjs-templateurl-vs-template-isolate-scope).

Should I provide a controller to the templates ? Or simply… so how can I extend the scope ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem came from the app bootstrapped too early i.e. before my framework was ready to provide the templates correctly and therefore AngularJS able to compile everything together.

I therefore replaced the bootstrapping from the `ng-app` directive to a manual one i.e.

```
Meteor.startup(function ()
{    
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Yes the framework was meteor...